# Unknown graphics extension

Tags: graphics, compiling, scientific-workplace

I have inserted a .wmf (Windows Metafile) into a Scientific Workplace document. Then I tried to convert it to pdf using MikTex 2.9.  I am getting this error message:

```
! LaTeX Error: Unknown graphics extension: .wmf.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
```

Saving my graphics to .eps or .bmp and then inserting it into the document does not help either.

What is going on?

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Did you try to convert it to `.png`?

Comment: Quick test conversion is to open PowerPoint and drag the wmf file into a slide.  Now right click on the picture and save as a png.  Be aware that there are better tools for converting which do a better job, but this will confirm for you that it can be converted to a png and be used by LaTeX.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it solved by cpomments.

Answer (score 1):

Well, `pdflatex` (and the other compilers similarly) does not recognize `.wmf` files and can't handle them. You first need to convert the `.wmf` file to something better: `.pdf`, `.png` or `.jpg`, depending on which is more suitable for the specific picture. (However, such a conversion is not in the scope of this site, obviously...)